# when try to pull an object from array in mongodb acknowledged: true, modifiedCount: 0, upsertedId: null, upsertedCount: 0, matchedCount: 1

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I'm trying to remove a product object from user cart when it's count reaches zero.

```js
changeProductCount : (details) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      if (details.count==-1 && details.quantity==1) {
        console.log();
        let response = await db.get().collection(CART_COLLECTION)
          .updateOne({
            $and: [
              { _id: ObjectId(details.cart) }, 
              { 'products.time': parseInt(details.time) }
            ]
          }, {
            $pull : {
              products : { item : ObjectId(details.item) }
            }
          });

        if (response) {
          console.log(response);
          resolve({ removeProduct: true })
        }
      } else {
        let response = await db.get().collection(CART_COLLECTION)
          .updateOne({
            _id: ObjectId(details.cart),
            'products.time': details.time
          }, {
            $inc : {
              'products.$.quantity': parseInt(details.count)
            }
          });

        if (response) {
          console.log(response);
          resolve({removeProduct:false})
        }
      } 
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
}
```

This is my code. I'm trying to pull an object from an array from the `userCart` when their product count is `0`.

Here, if I replace the code as this:

```js
let response = await db.get().collection(CART_COLLECTION)
  .updateOne({
    _id:ObjectId(details.cart)
  }, {
    $pull: {
      products: {
        item : ObjectId(details.item)
      }
    }
  }
);
```

This code is working, but the problem is, if there are two shirts with same product Id but different sizes, say Medium and Large, when medium is removed, large also gets removed. That's the reason why I added time for each objects when it is first added to cart. But, it is not working. Please help me in this problem.

This is the response that I get:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

Comment: When i try to pull out object in mongosh using this code :  db.cart.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("63b6a423adf0dab2ee57be14"), 'products.time': 1672913955547},{$pull : {'products' : {'item' : ObjectId("63ad21a73ff37cd424005816")}}}) ,    It is working properly and object is pulled out.

{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedCount: 0
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. This is the code that I used.

```
let response = await db.get().collection(CART_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id:ObjectId(details.cart)},{$pull : {products : {time : parseInt(details.time)}}});
```

As the time was already a unique value, I used it to match with the array object.